# asp.net project on iisexpress and localhost appending www to URL

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a asp.net project that im trying to run from VS2017 using iisexpress. If I go to http://localhost:33997, it redirects to http://www.localhost:33997 and returns a invalid hostname error. In Chrome, it redirects over and over and appends www over a dozen times. I dont see rewrites in the applicationconfig. I am at a loss.

Comment: Dig into your code base to see if it issues redirection from there. IIS is not the only place to check.

Comment: try to clear the history and cache of the browser. did you try to use another browser? Examine the response headers sent by the server when these redirects occur.The Network Inspection tools provided by Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox (browser tools). These tools can be used to record the requests made by your web browser, allowing you to inspect their response headers. also, check your code.

Comment: you could try to check the startup.cs file or your application and your launch setting. and try to create a new sample application in visual studio and test if it works well then there is something issue in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up being internet options adding prefixes to my typed URLs